# Remesh mod crashes my Blender

Tags: modifiers, error, remesh

I want to remesh a low poly model and if I set the voxel-size to something like 0,001 it crashes my blender. What can I do? :(

Also Im a blender noob...

PC specs:r7 5800x, 32gb ram, rtx 3070

Comment: Remesh is not kind for your hardware, so set the voxel size to something larger.

Comment: and i got like cpu usage 70% for 1 sec till it crashes and ram 50% or lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller the *Voxel Size* of the remesh operation is the more vertices are generated. The *Voxel Size* also depends on the size of your model. The bigger the model the more vertices will be generated for the same *Voxel Size*.

If you choose the *Voxel Size* too small a value then Blender tries to create several millions of vertices and crashes if it's too many for your hardware.

The remesh operation is available in *Sculpt* mode and via *Remesh* modifier.

To get a good value

- make sure the *Scale* is applied to your model (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode to apply it).
- go to *Sculpt* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> > *<kbd>2</kbd> Sculpt*)
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to set the voxel size in a visual way. It will display a grid and the squares represent the voxel size.
- move the mouse to change the value. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> for precise selection. Don't make the grid too dense. If you're happy use the value for the *Remesh* modifier.

[image: remesh voxel size]

For an immediate, destructive remesh you can execute the operation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in *Sculpt* mode.