# My sculpting brush is pulling not adding

Tags: sculpting, brushes

im fiddling around with sculpting and wanted to make a monster but when i try to add mesh with any brush it just pulls not adds[image]

i dont want it to do this any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe flipped normals? This can happen if you apply a negative scale. Then the mesh is inside out and you need to flip the normals.

Comment: how might i do this?

Comment: Enable the *[Face Orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/148669/107598)* overlay. If there is anything red is turned inside out. To fix it go to *Edit* mode, select everything (key A) and try *Recalculate Outside* (Alt+N). Alternatively, you can try the voxel remesher in *Sculpt* mode. But this can remove your sculpted details. It's Shift+R for the grid to see the voxel size, and Ctrl+R to remesh. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252944/107598